# Putting methods/code in the right places

Tags: c#, oop

I’m trying to get used with OOP, but sometimes i can’t get my head around it. In particular, in the field of making up methods for classes. I’m creating an Animal Shelter administration program that keeps track of all the animals and products it has. I’m currently working on applying functionality to the products section.

[image]

For clarity: In the main form i have an instance of the webshop, wherein i keep a list of products that are in the webshop and i have an users-list which also have a list of products that belong to each user.

When i was thinking about the class diagram i decided that an user has methods like this: sellProduct, buyProduct etc. The implementation of these methods then would be: removing product from user-list and adding them to the products-list of the webshop(sellProduct) and for the buyProduct conversely.

In my solution now, i have created an static instance of the webshop class, so all the other classes in my main form can access it:

```
static Webshop webshop = new Webshop();
```

The user class has these methods implemented:

```
    public void SellProduct(Product product)
    {
        products.Remove(product);
        AnimalForm.Webshop.Products.Add(product);
    }

    public void BuyProduct(Product product)
    {
        AnimalForm.Webshop.Products.Add(product);
        products.Add(product);
    }
```

Just removing the products from the products list in the user class and adding it to the products list of the webshop.

But then i thought can’t i just put these 2 rules in the event handler of the button that is clicked? If i do this in the main form i can just make only one instance of the webshop instead of making it static to make it accessible for other classes. But then the only thing i do in the classes is keeping up lists of products without any functionality.

And in the solution above i have these methods in the user class, but instead of having them in here i could also have them in the webshop class.

This kind of problem is the problem i wrestle with most of the time. Putting methods in the right places. How do you guys think about these choices?

Comment: Your question, as I understand it, really isn't a question about understanding OOP, but a software design pattern question. What design pattern are you using? MVC? MVVM? Not sure? Your diagram and intro shows you at least understand the basics of OOP, but your question is about event handling and where to put methods that change your model. I would read into design pattern to get a better understanding of how to design your application.

Comment: @Lithium At this moment i am using the repository pattern for serialization and deserialization of the list objects. The lists in the form and classes will be read out of a text file with the repository and when the application runs an user can perform operations on the list in-memory. When the application closes all these operations on the lists will be saved again with the repo. But always i see many different ways of designing these classes and at that moment i get confused. I will read into design patterns more, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a service class that is responsible for buying and selling products and leave the WebShop and the User as simple data objects.  You could have a TransactionService class that is responsible for buying and selling products.  That service class could have a Buy(Webshop shop, Product product, User user) method and a similar Sell method.  In this way, the TransactionService class would be responsible for making sure that all the relevant things happen (and potentially roll everything back if necessary) and could perform checks on stock etc.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So for my clarity, what you mean is: there will be a service class which has methods like this: **Buy(Webshop shop, Product product, User user) { shop.Products.Remove(product); user.Products.Add(product) }** and for the sell method reversed. You talk about leaving the webshop and user class as simple data objects. Is this a good practice, having classes without almost any functionality? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Yes, it can be good practice to have data object classes that represent entities with just properties and no methods